# PHP arrays in a while

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I have problem with $res array.... i don't know with $res[0] is like a empty variable (array have a lot of dates but i don't know why and where is wrong... i tried with $res['ItemSlotX'] and now with $res[0]...
Edited: i have already changed my $res[0] and 1 but is same...

Thank you for help!

```
function smartsearch($whbin,$itemX,$itemY) {
if (substr($whbin,0,2)=='0x') $whbin=substr($whbin,2);  
$items  = str_repeat('0', 240);
$itemsm = str_repeat('1', 240);
$i  = 0; 
while ($i<240) {
    $_item  = substr($whbin,(64*$i), 64);
    $type   = (hexdec(substr($_item,18,2))/16);
    $dbgetvalutslots = new DB_MSSQL;
    $dbgetvalutslots->Database='DTRMUWAP';
    $dbgetvalutslots->query("Select [ItemSlotX],[ItemSlotY] from ItemDetails where ItemIndex = '".hexdec(substr($_item,0,2))."' and ItemGroup = '".$type."'");
    $ijj=0;
    $res=array();
    while ($dbgetvalutslots->next_record()) {
    $temp = array(
    'ItemSlotX' => $dbgetvalutslots->f('ItemSlotX'),
    'ItemSlotY' => $dbgetvalutslots->f('ItemSlotY')     
    );
    $res[$ijj]=$temp;
    $ijj++;}
    $y  = 0;
    while($y<$res[1]) {
        $y++;
        $x=0;
        while($x<$res[0]) {
            $items  = substr_replace($items, '1', ($i+$x)+(($y-1)*8), 1);
            $x++;   
        } 
    }       
    $i++;
}$y = 0;
while($y<$itemY) {
    $y++;$x=0;
    while($x<$itemX) {
        $x++;
        $spacerq[$x+(8*($y-1))] = true;
    } 
}
$walked = 0;
$i  = 0;
while($i<120) {
    if (isset($spacerq[$i])) {
        $itemsm = substr_replace($itemsm, '0', $i-1, 1);
        $last   = $i;
        $walked++;
    }
    if ($walked==count($spacerq)) $i=119;
    $i++;}$useforlength = substr($itemsm,0,$last);
$findslotlikethis='^'.str_replace('++','+',str_replace('1','+[0-1]+', $useforlength));
$i=0;$nx=0;$ny=0;
while ($i<120) {
    if ($nx==8) { $ny++; $nx=0; }
    if ((eregi($findslotlikethis,substr($items, $i, strlen($useforlength)))) && ($itemX+$nx<9) && ($itemY+$ny<16))
        return $i;
    $i++;
    $nx++;
}
return 1337;}
```

Comment: this is not clear question and code is so dirty to understand...  sorry :(

Comment: `var_dump($res)` - it doesn't contain what you think it contains. Specifically - you're creating an array of arrays; and it's the sub-arrays that contain `ItemSlotY`, so you can't iterate through them in the way you're trying

Comment: Yes, please, do yourself a favour and re-format the code. And another advice: try to avoid (temporary) variables - e.g. you can get rid of `$ijj` but just using `$res[] = ...`. And $temp is superfluous as well `$res[] = array(
    'ItemSlotX' => $dbgetvalutslots->f('ItemSlotX'),
    'ItemSlotY' => $dbgetvalutslots->f('ItemSlotY')     
    );`. I guess more a matter of opinion are the `$x=0;while($x<something) { ...$x++}` constructs but I'd prefer a for-loop here to have everthing close together.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lack of context for the code in order to really understand it, but for what I can see here already, it should be:

**Edit**: some extra code to be more explicit

```
$y  = 0;
$numberOfRecords = count($res);
while($recordN < $numberOfRecords)
    while($y<$res[$recordN]["ItemSlotY"]) {
        $y++;
        $x=0;
        while($x<$res[$recordN]["ItemSlotX"]) {
            $items  = substr_replace($items, '1', ($i+$x)+(($y-1)*8), 1);
            $x++;   
        } 
    }       
    $i++;
    $recordN++;
}
```

as `$temp` is an array and you're then doing `$res[$ijj]=$temp;`

Comment: I don't understand... my head will explode

Comment: Each element of `$res` itself is an array. There is no `$res['ItemSlotY']` but e.g. `$res[0]['ItemSlotY']`.

Comment: like this?

  $res=array();
  while ($dbgetvalutslots->next_record()) {
  $temp = array(
  'ItemSlotX' => $dbgetvalutslots->f('ItemSlotX'),
  'ItemSlotY' => $dbgetvalutslots->f('ItemSlotY')  
  );
  $res[]=$temp;
}
  $y = 0;
  while($y<$res[1]) {
   $y++;
   $x=0;
   while($x<$res[0]) {
    $items = substr_replace($items, '1', ($i+$x)+(($y-1)*8), 1);
    $x++; 
   } 
  }  
  $i++;

Comment: Just a hunch: How many records do you expect there to be fetched via `while ($dbgetvalutslots->next_record()) {...}` ?

Comment: @user3430798 I edited my answer in order to be more explicit. This just tries to solve this very local problem. VolkerK makes some good points for the rest of the code.

Comment: I have edit my first post with full function end with $res[0] edited... but same problem..